# HTML Navigation Bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Need a help wit nav bar elements.**

I've got a problem changing Navigation Bar items style.

I want to change the text color from a default blue. Also, change hover color to the red one.

Changing nav-item parameter doesn't work.

I wonder what parameter need to be changed.

Thank you in advance.

Here is the code:

```css
.nav-item {
    color: #e0e0e0;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    }

    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
 <!-- Symbols coding -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">

 <!-- Window change, depends on the screen resolution  -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  
  <!-- Connecting Fonts library -->
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
 
 <!-- Connecting Bootstrap styles -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">

 <!-- Connecting personal style file(style.css) -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">

</head>

<body>

 <!-- Container to center navbar on the page and to center content in the navbar --> 
 <div class="container">

 <!-- Centered navbar, which become vertical on a small screen --> 
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm justify-content-center sticky-top" style="background-color: #313030;">

  <ul class="navbar-nav">
   <!-- Active - highlight the current link --> 
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
   
 </nav>

 </div>


   
 <div class="container">
   <h3>Basic Navbar Example</h3>
   <p>A navigation bar is a navigation header that is placed at the top of the page.</p>
 </div>
 


 <!-- jQuery library -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
 <!-- JS Bootstrap scripts --> 
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to apply the style on `nav-link` element instead of the `nav-item`.

```css
.nav-item .nav-link {
  color: #e0e0e0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.nav-item:hover .nav-link {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <!-- Symbols coding -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <!-- Window change, depends on the screen resolution  -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- Connecting Fonts library -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Connecting Bootstrap styles -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <!-- Connecting personal style file(style.css) -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">

</head>

<body>

  <!-- Container to center navbar on the page and to center content in the navbar -->
  <div class="container">

    <!-- Centered navbar, which become vertical on a small screen -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm justify-content-center sticky-top" style="background-color: #313030;">

      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <!-- Active - highlight the current link -->
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 3</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </nav>

  </div>



  <div class="container">
    <h3>Basic Navbar Example</h3>
    <p>A navigation bar is a navigation header that is placed at the top of the page.</p>
  </div>



  <!-- jQuery library -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- JS Bootstrap scripts -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! But how to apply hover to the box (not to text)?

 .nav-item:hover
{ color:red;}

Answer (score 0):

```
.nav-item a {
    color: #e0e0e0;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 }
 .nav-item a:hover{ color:red;}
```

use anchor tag for changing color